Vue3 migration, getting error vue is not defined
Trying the official migration guide: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html#installation
After adding point#3 code into my config file its like:
// vite.config.js
...
import vue2 from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
...
export default {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: '@vue/compat'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          compatConfig: {
            MODE: 2
          }
        }
      }
    }),
    vue2(),
  ]
}

but getting error vue is not defined, when running the dev mode.

import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

I have updated the question as I m already using plugin-vue2 as well, should I use plugin-vue now and remove vue2?

Sure,if you want use vue3.
